# C#: RSACryptoServiceProvider Encrypt and VerifyData?

Tags: c#, encryption, verify, rsacryptoserviceprovider

here are my methods for encrypting and decrypting data using RSA:

```
private RSACryptoServiceProvider _RSACSP { get; set; }

public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] value, bool doOAEPPadding)
{
    try
    {
        return (this._RSACSP.Encrypt(value, doOAEPPadding));
    }
    catch
    {
        return (null);
    }

}

public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] value, bool doOAEPPadding)
{
    try
    {
        return (this._RSACSP.Decrypt(value, doOAEPPadding));
    }
    catch
    {
        return (null);
    }
}
```

Now, how do I use `this._RSACSP.VerifyData(...);` to verify the encrypted data? I looked around and everything mentions `SHA1`, except I'm not even sure that's in use here.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not use (or need) it to verify the outcome of Encrypt/Decrypt.

VerifyData is used to verify a signature created with one of the SignData() overloads.

Signing data is another use of Asymmetric encryption.